# Деактивация input'a через время

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно чтобы после фокуса на инпуте, он через какое-то время становился не редактируемым.

```
<input type="text" id="one">
<input type="text" id="two">

$("input[type='text']").focus(function (){
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }, 3000);
});
```

Пробовал так, но не получилось

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setTimeout` вызывает функцию в глобальном контексте, где `this` это `window`.

```js
$("input[type='text']").focus(function (){
    var thisInput = this;
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(thisInput).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="one">
<input type="text" id="two">
```